# Running several background processes in linux using own shell script launcher

Tags: linux, shell, background-process

I would like to run several application instances in a remote Linux server which would run in a parallel way and also after logging out. I would like to launch them using a single shell script.

Let's say that I want to run the following commands in a parallel way:

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "matlab_test"
matlab -nodisplay -r "matlab_test2"
```

And let's say these processes update files named "test_file.mat" and "test_file2.mat" respectively as frequently as possible.

I tried several methods that I googled out, but here are the most representative ones.

1. I tried the following combination, in order to use it in the future shell script:

   ```
   matlab -nodisplay -r "matlab_test" &
   bg 1
   ```

   Result: the output file "test_file.mat" was not generated at all, so I 
   assume that the process was put to the background, but it was not running 
   there.

   Remark: When I fg this process, the file is generated.
2. I also tried:

   ```
   nohup matlab -nodisplay -r "matlab_test" &
   ```

   Result: the command prompt was occupied, which, as I assume, prevents from 
   calling the next commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `nohup matlab "matlab_test" &`

that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **screen** package. in most of Linux distributions, this package is already installed, but if not you can install it via the repository easily.

on Ubuntu and Debian

```
apt install screen
```

on CentOS and Fedora

```
yum install screen
```

To start a screen session, simply type screen in your console:

```
screen
```

You can detach from the screen session at any time by typing:

```
Ctrl+a d
```

The program running in the screen session will continue to run after you detach from the session.
To find the session ID list the current running screen sessions with:

```
screen -ls
There are screens on:
    10835.pts-0.linuxize-desktop   (Detached)
    10366.pts-0.linuxize-desktop   (Detached)
2 Sockets in /run/screens/S-linuxize.
```

and If you want to restore screen session:

```
screen -r 10835
```